# How to send a message from client to server using c# containg spaces

Tags: c#

I create the following code but there is one problem: I can't sent a large message from client to server which contains spaces.

Here is my code for server

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;


namespace ServerApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting: Creating Socket object");
            Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
            SocketType.Stream,
            ProtocolType.Tcp);
            listener.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 2112));
            listener.Listen(10);
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for connection on port 2112");
                Socket socket = listener.Accept();
                string receivedValue = string.Empty;
                while (true)
                {
                    if (socket.Available > 0)
                    {
                        byte[] receivedBytes = new byte[socket.ReceiveBufferSize];
                        int numBytes = socket.Receive(receivedBytes);
                        Console.WriteLine("Receiving...");
                        receivedValue += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedBytes);

                        break;

                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Received value: {0}", receivedValue);
                Console.WriteLine("Enter ur Msg");
                string replyValue = Console.ReadLine();
                //string replyValue = "Message successfully received.";
                byte[] replyMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(replyValue);
                socket.Send(replyMessage);
                socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                socket.Close();
            }
            listener.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my code for client

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace ClientApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            byte[] receivedBytes = new byte[2048];
            //IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.Resolve("192.168.1.55");
            IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.Resolve("127.0.0.1");
            IPAddress ipAddress = ipHost.AddressList[0];
            //IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 8000);
            IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 2112);
            Console.WriteLine("Starting: Creating Socket object");
            Socket sender = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,SocketType.Stream,ProtocolType.Tcp);
            sender.Connect(ipEndPoint);
            Console.WriteLine("Successfully connected to {0}",sender.RemoteEndPoint);
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Client Message :");
            string sendingMessage = Console.ReadLine();
            //string sendingMessage = "Hello World Socket Test";
            Console.WriteLine("Creating message:{0}",sendingMessage);
            byte[] forwardMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sendingMessage + "[FINAL]");
            sender.Send(forwardMessage);
            int totalBytesReceived = sender.Receive(receivedBytes);
            Console.WriteLine("Message provided from server: {0}",Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedBytes,0, totalBytesReceived));
            sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            sender.Close();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Please tell me the right way to do this.

Thanks in advance for you suggestions

Comment: You won't always get all the data in one go. Network packets often include a length field in the first few bytes so the receiver knows to keep reading until it has all the data to reform the packet on the far side of the network stream

Comment: sorry sir i am not getting just tell me what i do to solve my problem

Comment: I think it would be simpler if you just sent 4 bytes in advance (an `int`) which describe the length of the incoming message. Then you won't need to send `[FINAL]` and your message loop will be much shorter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Server**

```
Console.WriteLine("Starting: Creating Socket object");
Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
SocketType.Stream,
ProtocolType.Tcp);
listener.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 2112));
listener.Listen(10);
while (true)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Waiting for connection on port 2112");
  Socket socket = listener.Accept();
  string receivedValue = string.Empty;
  while (true)
  {
    if (socket.Available > 0)
    {
      do
      {
        var receivedBytes = new byte[socket.Available];
        socket.Receive(receivedBytes);
        Console.WriteLine("Receiving...");
        receivedValue += Encoding.Default.GetString(receivedBytes);
      } while (socket.Available > 0);
      break;
    }
  }
  Console.WriteLine("Received value: {0}", receivedValue);
  Console.WriteLine("Enter ur Msg");
  string replyValue = Console.ReadLine();
  //string replyValue = "Message successfully received.";
  byte[] replyMessage = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(replyValue);
  socket.Send(replyMessage);
  socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
  socket.Close();
}
listener.Close();
```

**Client**

```
byte[] receivedBytes = new byte[2048];
//IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.Resolve("192.168.1.55");
IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.Resolve("127.0.0.1");
IPAddress ipAddress = ipHost.AddressList[0];
//IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 8000);
IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 2112);
Console.WriteLine("Starting: Creating Socket object");
Socket sender = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
sender.Connect(ipEndPoint);
Console.WriteLine("Successfully connected to {0}", sender.RemoteEndPoint);
Console.WriteLine("Enter Client Message :");
string sendingMessage = Console.ReadLine();
//string sendingMessage = "Hello World Socket Test";
Console.WriteLine("Creating message:{0}", sendingMessage);
byte[] forwardMessage = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(sendingMessage);
sender.Send(forwardMessage);
int totalBytesReceived = sender.Receive(receivedBytes);
Console.WriteLine("Message provided from server: {0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedBytes, 0, totalBytesReceived));
sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
sender.Close();
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: no Problem :) i think now you will be able to implement the same in your Client.